# return to the position in matrix by

Tags: r

`comN<-gtools::permutations(2,5,v=c(0,1),repeats=TRUE)`

`which(comN==c(0,0,0,0,1),arr.ind.col=T)`

but it didn't give me the row number 2

I want to know c( 0,0,0,0,1) is on position comN [2,]

Comment: `which(colSums(t(comN) == c(0,0,0,0,1)) == ncol(comN))`.

Comment: Note that R's matrix operations are in column order, so the comparison in your `which` instruction compares the vector `c(0,0,0,0,1)` column by column, recycling it. This is why I needed the transpose `t()` in my solution above.

Comment: Or `which(apply(t(comN) == c(0,0,0,0,1), 2, all))`. The `colSums` solution is faster.

Answer (score 1):

R's matrix operations are in column order, so the comparison in your `which` instruction compares the vector `c(0,0,0,0,1)` column by column, recycling it. Just see what happens in this simple example.

```
m <- matrix(1:8, ncol = 2)
m
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    5
#[2,]    2    6
#[3,]    3    7
#[4,]    4    8

m == c(1, 5)
#      [,1]  [,2]
#[1,]  TRUE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE FALSE
#[3,] FALSE FALSE
#[4,] FALSE FALSE
```

The vector `c(1, 5)` is not compared with the first row, the comparisons are

```
c(1, 2) == c(1, 5)
```

then `c(1, 5)` is recycled and compared with the next values in the first column. So when it reaches the second column the first comparison in that column is

```
c(5, 6) == c(1, 5)
#[1] FALSE FALSE
```

returning `c(FALSE, FALSE)`.

This is why I needed the transpose `t()` in my solutions below. 
A way could be

```
which(colSums(t(comN) == c(0,0,0,0,1)) == ncol(comN))
#[1] 2
```

or

```
which(apply(t(comN) == c(0,0,0,0,1), 2, all))
```

The `colSums` solution is around 3 times faster.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sweep` to compare row-wise values of `comN` with the vector and use `rowSums` to count number of `TRUE` in each row

```
which(rowSums(sweep(comN, 2, c(0,0,0,0,1), `==`)) == ncol(comN))
#[1] 2
```

Instead of `rowSums`, we can also use `apply` since `sweep` already returns a matrix of logical vectors

```
which(apply(sweep(comN, 2,c(0,0,0,0,1), `==`), 1, all))
```